# Cant run android emulator on mac

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I try to run the android emulator i get:

```
ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
```

But I already have it installed from the sdk manager.

I'm using mac and the emulator i try to run is platform:5.0, cpu: google apis intel atom x86. Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the *SDK Manager* doesn't actually install *HAXM* even though it will say installed. It downloads the installer, which you must then *run to install* it to your machine.